# Eclipse maven project problem: Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-8

I imported a java/maven project, it runs ok in IntelliJ, but eclipse gives me this error.

[image]

I have JDK 8, and I don't understand why it's looking for tools.jar in maven repository.
[image]

I saw a similar question, but there the user is asking about java 11. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761785/pom-xml-marks-missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-8-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761785/pom-xml-marks-missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-8-0#)

any ideas anyone?

Comment: Try Right click on project->Maven -> Update Maven Dependencies and check the option for "Force Update of Snapshot/Releases".

Comment: @P.Sanjay I tried that multiple times, and a few others maven clean install etc .. No luck!

Comment: Please check below answers if that can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375423/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503460/could-not-find-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-7